# Gulp Compass Not Giving Any Output

Tags: sass, compass-sass, gulp

I am using gulp-compass, but it  is not giving me any output in my development directory. Following is my code (**not complete code**). Can anybody let me know what am I doing wrong?

```
var compass = require('gulp-compass');
if (env === 'development') {
    outputDir = 'builds/development/';
    sassStyle = 'expanded';
} else {
    outputDir = 'builds/production/';
    sassStyle = 'compressed';
}
sassSources = [
    'app/styles/components/style.scss'
];
gulp.task('compass', function() {
    gulp.src(sassSources)
        .pipe(compass({
            sass: 'app/styles',
            css: outputDir + 'css',
            image: outputDir + 'images',
            style: sassStyle,
            require: ['susy', 'breakpoint']
        }))
        .on('error', util.log)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + 'css'))
        .pipe(
            browserSync.reload({ stream: true })
        )
});
```

**Update**

Following code is working now.

```
sassSources = [
  './app/sass/**/*.scss'
];
gulp.task('compass', function() {
  gulp.src(sassSources)
    .pipe(compass({
      sass: './app/sass',
      css: outputDir + 'css',
      image: outputDir + 'images',
      style: sassStyle,
      require: ['susy', 'breakpoint']
    }))
    .on('error', util.log)
    .pipe(
      browserSync.reload({ stream: true })
    )
});
```

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Why do you have the `.pipe(gulp.dest(...))` commented out?

Comment: @JMM As far as I know, it's support was removed in few versions. I have uncommented it now.

Comment: Removed in few versions of what? You still don't get output after uncommenting it?